# Is there some way to see PS3 trophies from with the PS3 itself?

Tags: achievements, ps3

If I view my profile from the XMB, I can see only the eight most recent trophies. Is there some way to expand that view, or is that all you get from within the PS3 itself? Did I just miss something?

Also, if that's all the PS3 itself can show, what would be the official way to get a comprehensive list?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go to the PlayStation Network section of the XMB.  Near the bottom is an option for trophies. They are broken out by game, and allow you to see all available trophies.  The ones that you have earned already will be "lit up".

Comment: figures. hiding in plain sight.